# C++, with wrong input, default value is not printed out

Tags: c++

I'm working on [Bjarne_Stroustrup]Programming-Principles-and-Practice-Using-C++ book.
With the following code, the user enters his age in years and months; Then the program tells him/her how old is he/she:

```cpp
// This program shows your age.

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
        cout << "Please enter your age (years <space> months):\n";
        double ageYears = -1 , ageMonths = -1;
        cin >> ageYears >> ageMonths;
        cout << "Your age is " << ageYears << " years and " << ageMonths << " months.\n";
}
```

**Question:**
I put `string`s as input. It does not print out the default value `-1` for `Years`, but it does for `Months`. **Why?** (Actually, it prints out `Your age is 0 years and -1 months.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ formatted input works in two stages (this is simplified of course)

1. The stream is checked for an error state, if it is in an error
   state input is aborted immediately.
2. The stream is read and if the input characters can be converted to the type of variable being input then the variable is set to the converted value, otherwise the variable is set to zero and stream is placed in an error state.

Applying that to the two inputs you have, the first input of `ageYears` gets to step 2, where the conversion fails and the stream is place in an error state, leaving `ageYears` with value zero. Then the input of `ageMonths` happens but the stream is in an error state from the preceding operation, so the input is aborted at step 1 and `ageMonths` is left unchanged.

Comment: Given this piece of code: `int main () { int a , b;  cin >> a >> b; cout << a << " " << b;}`, if I give it `1.5 2.5` as inputs, output is `1  0` . Based on your saying, it converts `1.5` to `1` but the stream is not placed in an error state (because conversion was successful). Why it fails to convert the second input `2.5`?

Comment: @Alish You asked it to read an integer, so the reading stops when it gets to the first `.`. The you try to read a second integer but there's no legal integer that starts with `.` so the second read fails. Your mistake is thinking that the read stops at the space, but it stops before that.

Comment: Try this code with the same input to see what I mean `int main () { int a; float b; cin >> a >> b; cout << a << " " << b;}`. The output should be `1 0.5`

Comment: Yes, I got it. Therefore, when my code starts to read `.5` from input stream, it gets to step 2 that you mentioned above, i.e. the code tries to convert `.5` to `int`, but as the conversion fails, the stream is placed in an error state, leaving `b` with value zero; right?

Comment: @Alish That's it.